# Column in where clause is ambiguous - What does that mean?

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysql-error-1052

I've come across this error in MySQL for the join clause but I'm fairly new to the `JOIN` argument and I'm not sure what this means. Can anyone help?

> Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT * FROM (`venues`) 
JOIN `venues_meta` ON `venues_meta`.`venue_id` = `venues`.`id` 
WHERE `id` = '12'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to fully qualify `id` because `venues` and `venues_meta` both have a column called `id`.

Comment: so just to make it clear for others... it needs to become WHERE venues.id = 12

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT * FROM `venues` v, `venues_meta` m  where v.venue_id = m.id AND  m.id = '12'
```

(but be sure it's v.venue_id you want and not v.id)

Comment: Your commas aren't quite correct if you're trying to alias `venues` as `v` and `venues_meta` as `m`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code

```html
SELECT v.*
FROM `venues` AS `v` 
INNER JOIN `venues_meta` AS `vm` ON `vm`.`venue_id` = `v`.`id` 
WHERE `v`.`id` = '12'
```

Comment: Please explain your code a little bit more and what your solution is

Comment: I created an alias for code compactness. And specify which table explicitly select `id` column