# Join two table getting some error in codeigniter php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to join 2 table, but getting some error. See the below code.

**Error-:**

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1052
>
> Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous
>
> SELECT * FROM `fuel_item` JOIN `fuel_unit` ON `fuel_item`.`unitid` =
>   `fuel_unit`.`id` WHERE `user_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC
>
> Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/fuel/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

```
 <?php 

    $query = $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->from('fuel_item');
    $query = $this->db->join('fuel_unit', 'fuel_item.unitid = fuel_unit.id');
    $query = $this->db->where('user_id',$_SESSION['user']);
    $query = $this->db->order_by('id','Desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
           {
  ?>
```

Comment: Add `alias` to your table names and then use that `alias` in `user_id`. The error is because column `user_id` is present in both tables `fuel_item` and `fuel_unit`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql ...in where clause is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678777/). Also see [Where clause is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021434/), ['user_id' in where clause is ambiguous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788326/), [Column in where clause is ambiguous - What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062185/), and [Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632441/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that both tables in the query have the column user_id. So you need name which table column you want.

For where condition prefixing the reference with either the full table name will fix this error.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*');
$query = $this->db->from('fuel_item');
$query = $this->db->join('fuel_unit', 'fuel_item.unitid = fuel_unit.id');
$query = $this->db->where('fuel_item.user_id',$_SESSION['user']);
$query = $this->db->order_by('fuel_item.id','Desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

change the where clause from `'user_id'` to `'fuel_item.user_id'` to prevent ambiguous column :

```php
 <?php 

    $query = $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->from('fuel_item');
    $query = $this->db->join('fuel_unit', 'fuel_item.unitid = fuel_unit.id');
    $query = $this->db->where('fuel_item.user_id',$_SESSION['user']);
    $query = $this->db->order_by('fuel_item.id','Desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
           {
  ?>
```

Comment: Error Number: 1052

Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM `fuel_item` JOIN `fuel_unit` ON `fuel_item`.`unitid` = `fuel_unit`.`id` WHERE `fuel_item`.`user_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/fuel/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: yes sir but gating some error

Comment: (id and user_id) is user two table

Comment: what is the error message shows up?

Comment: error herr: Error Number: 1052

Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM `fuel_item` JOIN `fuel_unit` ON `fuel_item`.`unitid` = `fuel_unit`.`id` WHERE `fuel_item`.`user_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/fuel/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: I've also updated the `order_by` codes, have you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the where condition

```
 $query = $this->db->where('user_id',$_SESSION['user']);
```

to

```
$query = $this->db->where('fuel_item.user_id',$_SESSION['user']);
```

You have to tell the MySQL that `user_id` exists in which table while using join.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $query = $this->db->select('*');  
    $query = $this->db->from('fuel_item fi');
    $query = $this->db->join('fuel_unit fu', 'fi.unitid = fu.id');
    $query = $this->db->where('fi.user_id',$_SESSION['user']);
    $query = $this->db->order_by('fi.id','Desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
           {
  ?>
```